# Rotate 2D viewable in viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am looking to be able to rotate a 2D viewable through a button click.

I have seen that it can be down with a mouse using the roll tool, but I want to be able to rotate the viewable through 90 degrees at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code show how to rotate a set of fragIds around a specific axis and center, if you want to rotate the full model, you need to rotate all the fragments:

```
// Rotate selected fragments
rotateFragments (model, fragIdsArray, axis, angle, center) {

  var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()

  quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axis, angle)

  fragIdsArray.forEach((fragId, idx) = > {

    var fragProxy = this.viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(
      model, fragId)

    fragProxy.getAnimTransform()

    var position = new THREE.Vector3(
      fragProxy.position.x - center.x,
      fragProxy.position.y - center.y,
      fragProxy.position.z - center.z)

    position.applyQuaternion(quaternion)

    position.add(center)

    fragProxy.position = position

    fragProxy.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(
      quaternion, fragProxy.quaternion)

    fragProxy.updateAnimTransform()
  })
}

// get leaf node fragIds
static getLeafFragIds (model, leafId) {

  const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree

  const fragIds = []

  instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(
      leafId, (fragId) => {
      fragIds.push(fragId)
  })

  return fragIds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have tried something close to what you are looking to do, but maybe you will need to do some research on your side to check if the scene can get updated at the time of clicking the button with the model already in the scene, I would think calling `viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true)` would do the trick but I'm not sure, also keep in mind this function does not seem to be public so there is no good documentation on it.

So let me explain what I have tried before. I built a sample where you have a 2D Lot model which after selection on one of the polylines or hatches of the lots you can add a 2nd model representing a house. The sample have 3 buttons on the left bottom corner and there is an input box that allows you to input a value from 0-360 degrees in order to load the 2nd model with the rotation you want.

Here is the link to the repo which also contains a link to a demo.
https://github.com/jaimerosales/viewer-dwgoffset

Here is a function that might give you an Idea, I would try loading the model and then apply the transformation followed by the Scene Update I mentioned before.

```
applyTransform (model) {

  var viewer = this._viewer

  // This is use for Transformation on 3D models, for 2D only pass rotation 
  // value on Z axis

  var euler = new THREE.Euler(
    model.transform.rotation.x * Math.PI/180,
    model.transform.rotation.y * Math.PI/180,
    model.transform.rotation.z * Math.PI/180,
    'XYZ')

  var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()

  quaternion.setFromEuler(euler)

  function _transformFragProxy (fragId) {

    var fragProxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(
      model,
      fragId)

    fragProxy.getAnimTransform()

    fragProxy.position = model.transform.translation

    fragProxy.scale = model.transform.scale

    //Not a standard three.js quaternion
    fragProxy.quaternion._x = quaternion.x
    fragProxy.quaternion._y = quaternion.y
    fragProxy.quaternion._z = quaternion.z
    fragProxy.quaternion._w = quaternion.w

    fragProxy.updateAnimTransform()
  }

  var fragCount = model.getFragmentList().
    fragments.fragId2dbId.length

  //fragIds range from 0 to fragCount-1
  for (var fragId = 0; fragId < fragCount; ++fragId) {

    _transformFragProxy(fragId)
  }
}
```